# How to let content push right-aligned image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a section with a text on the left side and a background image tied to a right side of a browser. Both text and image have about 50% width while using desktop device.

For desktop device solution, I've coded it like this:
http://www.bootply.com/xxyOcA9N5n

However, problem arises when I try to make it responsive. My preferred goal would be that the content gradually "pushes" background image to the right (out of the browser's "canvas"). In extreme case, it would look like this:[image] Image nearly disappeared and text is readable.

Can you please help me figure out, how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another col-sm-6 and place the image in there with a 100% width so it scales as the size gets smaller. You can also use [media queries](http://devdocs.io/css/media_queries) to define how you want it to look at various sizes.

```
<div class="container-fluid hp-about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h2>Company</h2>
                    <p class="large">We are doing this and this and it is
                    awesome because this and that. Yeah and also this and that.
                    And also that.</p>
                    <p><a href="#">More about us »</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6"><img src=
                "http://i.imgur.com/HGp1ot6.png"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, went with this. Also just for the sake of completeness, it works now flawlessly with left div being "col-sm-6 col-xs-9" and other one "col-sm-6 col-xs-3".

Furthermore to force image to "hug" the right side on large devices (that means to prevent container's padding) I've added:  

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.col-hug-right {
 right: -240px;
}}

and overflow-x:hidden on container